# why a dropdown selection passes nil as parameter?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i have created a dropdown in my application using the following code:

```
<% form_for :categories, :url=> {:controller => 'products', :action => 'cat'} do |f| %>
<%= f.select(:category ,  Categories.all.map{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }, :prompt => "Select a    category") %>
<input type="submit" value="go"/>
<%end%>
```

controller:

```
def cat
 @products = Product.search_category params[:category]
end
```

it is returning 'nil' as the parameter when i select any category from dropdown. what could be the reason?

Comment: can you post the parameters which are getting in controller action?

Comment: i have edited my question with controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect the category id to be in `params[:categories][:category]` because that's how the form was set up.  If you want to use `params[:category]`, pass a name option to `select`

```
<%= f.select :category, Categories.all.map{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }, { :prompt => "Select a category" }, { name: 'category' } %>
```

That aside, I find it better to use `collection_select` when you're dealing with an ActiveRecord table

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, Categories.all, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Select a category' }, { name: 'category' } %>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem lies with your symbol used with form_for. Generally, a object is passed to form for as it will generate the proper routes.

This question is discussed here

[fields_for doesnt working when form_for use symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053849/fields-for-doesnt-working-when-form-for-use-symbol)

and

[Ruby on Rails : symbol as argument in form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006329/ruby-on-rails-symbol-as-argument-in-form-for)